# Are C++ floats guaranteed to have infinity?

Tags: c++, floating-point, infinity

In standards compliant C++, is the following guaranteed to be true?

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity
```

Comment: Well, of course not, what would be the point of coming up with a different symbol for 'true'.  That's a thought that could occupy one's mind for ever.

Comment: @Hans: It could be guaranteed `true` for `float` but not for all specializations of `std::numeric_limits`. Compare the fact that `numeric_limits<float>::is_integer` is guaranteed to be `false`, but it does not follow that `numeric_limits::is_integer` is a redundant funny way of saying `false`. Traits classes are template meta-functions.

Comment: Clearly Steve has been thinking about it longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but doesn't that depend on the value of `is_iec559`, (Tests if a type conforms to IEC-559 / IEEE-754 standard)?

Comment: You're right that if `is_iec559 != false`, then there is an infinity (18.2.1.2/33). I believe you're also right that otherwise there doesn't have to be. The standard contains the string "infinit" very few times, and none of them that I can find mention that floating point types have to have one.

Answer (score 1):

It should, assuming that your library implementation follows the C++ standards and uses a float that has an infinity.

Comment: float with inf can be generated without any library.

Comment: True, but the question appeared to be about a library feature.

Comment: The question wasn't about an implementation ("In standards compliant C++"). Besides, your answer is a tautology: it's guaranteed to have an infinity assuming it has an infinity.

Comment: No my answer was not a tautology. Not every platform utilizes floating point numbers that have an infinity. As a consequence the numeric trait can be false in some cases.